# procedimiento almacenado

Tags: mysql, stored-procedure

buenas tardes amigos a ver si pueden darme una mano con esta pregunta:
estoy ejecutando un procedimiento almacenado en MYSQL y dentro de este procedimiento tengo un cursor como se muestra:

```
CREATE DEFINER=root@localhost PROCEDURE `sp_salida`(IN `_id` INT, IN `_idDocumento` INT, IN `_serieDocumento` VARCHAR(50), IN `_numeroDocumento` VARCHAR(50), IN `_tipoPago` INT, IN `_valorImpuesto` INT, IN `_cantidad` INT, IN `_tipo` VARCHAR(50), IN `_fechaVenta` DATE, IN `_usuaCreaModi` INT, IN `_fechCreaModi` DATETIME)

BEGIN
DECLARE _rollback BOOL DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION SET _rollback = 1;

INSERT INTO temp_salida_detalle(id_prod,id_emsu,cant_vent,id_usua,esta_vent)
SELECT hk.id_prod,@idEmpresaSucursal,hk.cant_sali,_usuaCreaModi,'V'
FROM his_kardex hk
WHERE hk.usua_crea=_usuaCreaModi AND hk.id_emsu=@idEmpresaSucursal
AND hk.esta_kard='A';

/*CURSOR*/
CALL sp_cursorProductoSalidaKardex(@idEmpresaSucursal,_usuaCreaModi);


IF _rollback THEN
ROLLBACK;
SELECT 60 AS resultado;//DEVUELVE PARAMETRO SI HAY ALGUN PROBLEMA
ELSE
COMMIT;
SELECT 100 AS resultado;//DEVULVE PARAMETRO SI ES EXITOSO
END IF;
/*TERMINA STORE*/
```

Todo funciona correctamente, el problema es que cuando termina de ejecutar todo incluyendo el CURSOR ya no entra en el IF del rollback o commit y no devuelve nada.

cuando quito el cursor, todo se ejecuta y entra al IF y me devuelve el valor 100 0 60, sin embargo al volverlo a poner (el CURSOR) todo se ejecuta incluyendo el cursor pero ya no alcanza el IF, en consecuencia el STORE no me devuelve ni un valor (60 o 100), no se porque, por favor amigos si alguien sabe el porque le agradecería muchísimo su aporte.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Si necesitas editar tu pregunta, usa el boton [edit]

Answer (score 1):

**Primero:** Veo que en el procedimiento almacenado 'sp_salida' defines muchos parámetros de entradas que luego no utilizas:

```
... PROCEDURE `sp_salida`(
    IN `_id` INT, 
    IN `_idDocumento` INT, 
    IN `_serieDocumento` VARCHAR(50), 
    IN `_numeroDocumento` VARCHAR(50), 
    IN `_tipoPago` INT, 
    IN `_valorImpuesto` INT, 
    IN `_cantidad` INT, 
    IN `_tipo` VARCHAR(50), 
    IN `_fechaVenta` DATE, 
    IN `_usuaCreaModi` INT, -- Este sí lo utilizas
    IN `_fechCreaModi` DATETIME)
...
```

al menos no lo muestras en el código, voy a suponer que omitiste esa parte.

**Segundo:** Cuando realizas varias tareas en un procedimiento almacenado, es muy recomendado que las envuelvas en una transacción:

```
 START TRANSACTION;
        --insert ...
        --CALL sp_cursorProductoSalidaKardex()...
    COMMIT;
```

**Tercero:** Como llamas otro procedimiento almacenado desde éste,

```
CALL sp_cursorProductoSalidaKardex(@idEmpresaSucursal,_usuaCreaModi);
```

debes de cambiar tu estructura de control de errores, pues como saber si dentro del procedimiento que llamas hay otros errores, también debiste mostrarnos el código de ese procedimiento que llamas *CURSOR* y así darte una respuesta como ayuda mas concreta.

**Cuarto:** Utilizas la variable `@idEmpresaSucursal`, en la cual no se muestra en tu código donde se le asigna un valor.

**Quinto:** Como buena práctica, trata de mejorar el nombre del procedimiento almacenado, ya que por si solo no describe lo que hace. 'sp_salida', pero salida de que?.

**Ejemplo:**

```
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE DEFINER=root@localhost PROCEDURE `sp_salida`(
    IN `_usuaCreaModi` INT, 
    OUT p_mierror_cod   INT(11),
    OUT p_mierror_msg   TEXT)

MODIFIES SQL DATA
COMMENT 'Aqui la descripcion de la funcionalidad que realiza este proc'

BEGIN

    DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION, SQLWARNING
    BEGIN
        SHOW ERRORS LIMIT 1;
        RESIGNAL;       

    ROLLBACK;
        GET DIAGNOSTICS CONDITION 1 @RETURNED_SQLSTATE = RETURNED_SQLSTATE, @MYSQL_ERRNO = MYSQL_ERRNO, @MESSAGE_TEXT = MESSAGE_TEXT;
        SET p_mierror_cod = -10;
        SET p_mierror_msg = CONCAT("ERRNO: ",@MYSQL_ERRNO, ", SQLSTATE: ", @RETURNED_SQLSTATE, ", TEXT: ", @MESSAGE_TEXT);
    END;

    START TRANSACTION; 

        INSERT INTO temp_salida_detalle(id_prod,id_emsu,cant_vent,id_usua,esta_vent)
        SELECT hk.id_prod,@idEmpresaSucursal,hk.cant_sali,_usuaCreaModi,'V'
        FROM his_kardex hk
        WHERE hk.usua_crea=_usuaCreaModi AND hk.id_emsu=@idEmpresaSucursal
        AND hk.esta_kard='A';

        /*CURSOR*/
        CALL sp_cursorProductoSalidaKardex(@idEmpresaSucursal,_usuaCreaModi);

         -- Exitosamente        
        SET p_mierror_msg = 'La Salida se ejecutó correctamente.';

    COMMIT;

/*TERMINA STORE*/
END ;;
DELIMITER ;
```

Como puedes darte cuenta, solo dejé un parámetro de entrada, que es el único que utilizas, ademas agrego dos parámetros de salida, en los cuales almaceno el código y el mensaje de error reales (si los hubiera) que me da el **DBMS**, porque devolver 60 en caso de ser exitoso la ejecución o 100 en caso contrario, no me dice nada como programador para corregir un problema.

**Para llamar este proc:**

```
CALL sp_salida(
                _usuaCreaModi,
                @p_mierror_cod, 
                @p_mierror_msg 
              );
```

Espero que te ayuden estos comentarios.!

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta Gerónimo Fernández, mil disculpas por no mostrar el ejemplo completo sin embargo veo mucha lógica en tus comentarios y código, voy a probar lo que indicas, igualmente volveré a subir el ejemplo correcto y completo así como lo indicas, muchas gracias amigo.

Comment: estimado geronimo, nuevamente gracias por tu respuesta, quería hacer una consulta, como seria la estructura de control si tuviera un cursor dentro de otro cursor,  del ejemplo anterior si dentro del cursor CALL sp_cursorProductoSalidaKardex(@idEmpresaSucursal,_usuaCreaModi); existiera un cursor, teniendo en cuenta que debería funcionar las transacciones hasta en ese ultimo cursor.